# @SpringBootTest annotation giving Failed to load ApplicationContext Error

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

New to spring. I am trying to upgrade spring-boot-starter-parent from v1.3.2 to the latest v2.1.4. Made the POM file change for version upgrade. I have made all the necessary code changes to solve the compilation problems. when I am trying to  run the test cases though, Test Classes which have @SpringBootTest annotation are failing with java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext 
 I have my application properties(application.properties) file in src/main/resources and the test application.properties file in src/text/resources

I have tried various annotations like

```
    @ContextConfiguration()

    @TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application.properties")
```

Still received the same error. 
Below is the sample test class created.

```
    package xxx.xx.xx.xxxx.controller 
    import org.junit.Assert;

    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @SpringBootTest(classes = App.class)
    @WebAppConfiguration


    public class SampleTest {

            //sample test case created to figure out 
            //test case runs successful when @SpringBootTest is not present
            @Test
            public void sampleTest1() {
                int x= 2+3;
                Assert.assertEquals(5, x);
            }
    }
```

I expect to able to run the test cases with that annotation.

Comment: Remove @RunWith annotation.

Comment: I have written a sample test case to tell even it fails for simple ones. My actual test cases are with mocking and webapplicationContext. When I tried your suggestion received the below error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WebApplicationContext is required
 at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:198)